# Jquery pass multiple arrays to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to send 4 js arrays to a php page using AJAX, once there I want them in 4 php arrays for use in the php script.

Using `$.type(var)` I've confirmed my js arrays are actually arrays.

Using the following to send one array works :

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            cache: false,
            url: "test.php",    
            data : arrayA: arrayA,
            success: function(res) {
                console.log (res)
            }
        });
```

But the following fails:

```
var data = { arrayA: arrayA, arrayB: arrayB, arrayC: arrayC, arrayD: arrayD }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                cache: false,
                url: "test.php",    
                data : data,
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log (res)
                }
            });
```

My php page is :

```
$arrayA = $_REQUEST['arrayA'];
$arrayB = $_REQUEST['arrayB'];
$arrayC = $_REQUEST['arrayC'];
$arrayD = $_REQUEST['arrayD'];
```

I'm sure I'm missing the obvious, can some one advise please.

Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Could try putting all those arrays into ONE array in JS , then passing that array through, php I use `$_POST['array'];` in this instance

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  No error is shown, nothing seems to happen. How do I combine it into one array and then split it back out in PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to try this, this method should work:

```
// Create the arrays you want
var arrayA = ["cat","dog"];  
var arrayB = ["lamp","rock"];

// Combine the arrays into one
var array = [arrayA, arrayB];


 // Send them via ajax
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            cache: false,
            url: "test.php",    
            data : array: array,
            success: function(res) {
                console.log (res)
            }
        });
```

PHP side:

```
<?php
 // (use print_r($_POST) to see what comes through and how it is setup in the POST array, that way you can get the keys and names and build it out how you wish
  foreach($_POST['array'] as $array){
      // This will give each array, you could also get the array keys and use those as names if you wish
  }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go. Once it's in PHP how do i return it to the individual arrays ?

Comment: it will come through as an array of those arrays, use a foreach($_POST as $array) then create dynamically named arrays or what you will

Comment: Thanks I'll try this shortly

Comment: Thanks I've got this working using json stringify and then json_decode in my php